# Swift 4 Alamofire multipart upload not working

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4, multipart, xcode9.2

I am using alamofire 4.7 and swift 4

I need to upload image and json to server.

I am using the following code below for uploading bu  I am getting result failure but data is inserting in server but not getting response, showing some serialization error as something like this

```
▿ result : FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
    ▿ failure : AFError
      ▿ responseSerializationFailed : ResponseSerializationFailureReason
  ▿ timeline : Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 548835779.066, "Initial Response Time": 548835779.074, "Request Completed Time": 548835779.127, "Serialization Completed Time": 548835779.127, "Latency": 0.008 secs, "Request Duration": 0.061 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.061 secs }
    - requestStartTime : 548835779.06617701
    - initialResponseTime : 548835779.07390201
    - requestCompletedTime : 548835779.12704694
    - serializationCompletedTime : 548835779.12748504
    - latency : 0.0077250003814697266
    - requestDuration : 0.060869932174682617
    - serializationDuration : 0.00043809413909912109
    - totalDuration : 0.061308026313781738
  ▿ _metrics : Optional<AnyObject>
```

=================================================================

```
        let auth : String = MitraModal.sharedInstance().getBasicAuthenticationString()
    let headers = ["Authorization": auth, "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        multipartFormData.append("\(parameters)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "data" as String)

        if (!imageArray.isEmpty) {

            for item in imageArray {
                multipartFormData.append(item!, withName: "file", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }
        }

    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
        switch result{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value
                {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    onCompletion?(JSON as? JSON)

                    print("Successfully uploaded")
                }

                if let err = response.error {
                    onError?(err)
                    return
                }
                onCompletion?(nil)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            onError?(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone help ?

Comment: Please check what actual you are getting in response. I think this will help you to find error.

Comment: share your error also.

Comment: Error I updated, plz check

Answer (score 3):

As i'm newbie, but Few days ago, i had same problem while uploading image, you must have to accept image by using **file** on the server side because of your image tag consist **withName: "file"** .

```
func AlamofireUploadImages(){

    let url : String = URL_IP+"/ZameenServer/api/addNewProperty.php"
    for img in HOUSEImages{
        let data  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!
        ImagesData.append(data)
    }

    let parameters = [
        "userId"                : "5",
        "unit"                  : "6789"
    ] //Optional for extra parameter

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for imageData in self.ImagesData {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file[]", fileName: self.randomString(length: 5)+".jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: key)
        } //Optional for extra parameters
    },
                     to:url)
    { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON
                {
                    response in
                    print("Response :\(response.result.value)")
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("no Error :\(encodingError)")
        }
    }

}
```

**NOTE**: As i'm uploading array of images so for uploading multile images use **withName: "file[]"** or for single image use **withName: "file"**

Might be it helps you.

Thanks

Comment: I need to send text file and image file, is working in rest client

Comment: You need to download the document into the local file system, and then use another call to read data from it and convert it into the kind of object that your current View can display. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-upload-a-text-file-into-an-application-using-Swift

Comment: text means  json data parameters a little large data [String : Any], it is working in rest client not with alamofire, okay I will try once

Comment: Try try and try :)

Comment: Also i need a help from you i you can please see at my Question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492284/issue-with-activity-indicator-while-loading-data-in-uitableview]

Comment: Ok I will try that question,,,,tried but still same error

Comment: which web service you are using? mean php or anyother

Comment: backend is java

Comment: I have not hands on Java

Comment: alamofire which version u using?

Answer (score 0):

```
   let url = BaseViewController.API_URL + "uploads"
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!

    let parameters = [
                            "user_id" : UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userId")!
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "uload_data",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        } //Optional for extra parameters
    },
                     to:url)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                self.objHudHide()
                print(response.result.value)

                let jsonDict : NSDictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary

                print(jsonDict)
                if  jsonDict["status"] as! String == "Success"
                {


                    let detailDict : Dictionary = jsonDict["detail"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>

                    if let getTotalPrice = detailDict["total_price"]
                    {
                        self.lblTotalPrice.text = "$ \(getTotalPrice) + Free Shipping"
                    }

                    if  let getTotalSize = detailDict["total_upload_size"]
                    {
                        self.lblTotalSize.text = "Total Size : \(getTotalSize)"

                    }
                }
               else
                {

                let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Alert!", comment: ""), message:"Something Went wrong please try again." , preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), style: .default) { (action) -> Void in

                }
                alertViewController.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the similar issue as well. This may cause several reasons. In my case that was the error of parameter key of the POST request. When you are executing following line

```
multipartFormData.append(item!, withName: "file", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
```

`withName:"file"` property refers the parameter key (key of the Json request) for the image of the POST request. So you can't use whatever the text you want here. Please add the correct parameter key of the image that your API is referring instead of `"file"`. Let's say API access the image using "fileImage" as the parameter key. So the above line should be something like this.

```
multipartFormData.append(item!, withName: "fileImage", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
```