# Uploading an image with Alamofire not succeeding

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to do a POST request to an endpoint with body parameters img (an image) and id (can be any number).

This works in Postman (the server never responds with fail/success though unless when the `id` is missing):

[image]

However, on the iOS app side:

```
class func postPreviewImage(operaID: Int, image: UIImage, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let URL_CORDINATE = "http://artaugmentedreality.com/api/postpreview/"
    print("Trying to post a preview of opera with ID:", operaID)

    guard let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else {
        print("Error while retrieving image data")
        return
    }

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "img", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        multipartFormData.append(operaID.data, withName: "id")
    },
                     to: URL_CORDINATE,
                     method: .post)
    { (result) in
        print("Result of Alamofire call is", result)

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("Error while uploading image:", encodingError)
        }
    }
}

extension Int {
    var data: Data {
        var int = self
        return Data(bytes: &int, count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
    }
}
```

it is uploading but somehow the server is not receiving it. Could there be something wrong in my request code? I'm getting a:

```
Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
atyp = http;
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
ptcl = http;
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sdmn = "artaugmentedreality.com";
srvr = "artaugmentedreality.com";
sync = syna;
}
```

error code from Alamofire, perhaps because the domain isn't HTTP. However, I included the domain in the list of allowed domains in info.plist:

[image]

So I'm clueless about how to go from here.

Comment: Hi @Cesare! I have already given the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489453/swift-4-alamofire-multipart-upload-not-working/50502614#50502614

Comment: Thanks! I see you're passing all parameters as [String: String], however, my id is an integer. Do you think it matters if I'm passing an integer data instead of string data in the body parameters?

Comment: I exactly don't know, but I think it might cause the problem...

Comment: can't see this key "Allow Arbitrary Loads" in a plist file.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh added now but doesn't change things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending ID parameter along with the Image. So try to use utf8 encoding.

```
 multipartFormData.append(operaID.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "id")
```

Comment: operaID is an Integer though, so the `data(using:)` isn't available. Should I convert the id to a string first?

Comment: Yeah try that too :)